# genymotion start button disabled

Tags: android, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion of google nexus 7 2013-4.4.4-API19-1200*1920 in WINDOWS 7. I have configured with android studio and when I click on Genymotion device manager ,the start button is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

1. normally, the start button will enabled when selecting the genymotion device.
2. if not, verify that whether the genymotion's sdk is same as that of android studio  or not.

*Genymotion -> Setting -> ADB*

if it is, **Use Genymotion Android tools**. then change to **Use custom Android sdk tools**. and locate the sdk location.

[image: screen shot]

to know the sdk location,

*Android studio -> Preferences -> Appearance and behaviour -> System settings -> Android sdk -> Android sdk location*

[image]